# Does WhatsApp Cloud API offer specific endpoints for both inbound and outbound voice calls?

Tags: rest, integration, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have searched for WhatsApp Cloud API documentation, but I am only able to find API endpoint for messages. Do they have any public API for calling?

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't support calls of any kind. I have seen some services that handle information about missed calls, but it seems to be even unofficial